# WordPress .click or .on is not working while loaded from function.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I had this script working before when it was just an inline script on a WordPress page. But now I load it from `function.php`.

This works fine for my other JavaScript scripts, but .click or .on won't work on this script...

```
$( "td.event-test" ).on("click",
  function() {
    $("p").empty();
    $(".event-title").empty();
    $(".event-title2").empty();
    $("<h1>EVENT #01</h1>").appendTo(".event-title");
    $("<p>Here is information for event!</p>").appendTo(".event-info");
    $("<p>more info for event</p>").appendTo(".more-event-info");
    $("<p><a>LINK TO EVENT SITE</p></a>").appendTo(".event-link");
    $("a").attr("href", "events");
  }
);
```

It won't work, and the `.click` version won't work either:

```
$( "td.event-test" ).click(
  function() {
    $("p").empty();
    $(".event-title").empty();
    $(".event-title2").empty();
    $("<h1>EVENT #01</h1>").appendTo(".event-title");
    $("<p>Here is information for event!</p>").appendTo(".event-info");
    $("<p>more info for event</p>").appendTo(".more-event-info");
    $("<p><a>LINK TO EVENT SITE</p></a>").appendTo(".event-link");
    $("a").attr("href", "events");
  }
);
```

It loads the script as I can see console.log printing "test" string from the first line of the JavaScript script.

Comment: Did you put that code inside a proper DOM ready handler with no-conflict, as required by Wordpress, and did you include it with `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: This lines are the same thing.... under the hood, `click(` changes to on("click"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on("click","td.event-test",function() {
    $("p").empty();
    $(".event-title").empty();
    $(".event-title2").empty();
    $("<h1>EVENT #01</h1>").appendTo(".event-title");
    $("<p>Here is information for the event!</p>").appendTo(".event-info");
    $("<p>More info for the event</p>").appendTo(".more-event-info");
    $("<p><a>LINK TO THE EVENT SITE</p></a>").appendTo(".event-link");
    $("a").attr("href", "events");
});
```

Note: I have added this answer, because I saw `on()` in OP's code, so I thought that the OP was thinking `on()` will directly work for dynamically generated elements also, which is not right. That's why I added this solution so that it will work for both scenarios.

Comment: you da mvp, need to wait 10min to accept answer.

Comment: @Clomez  glad to help you :):)